# Android : Values of static fields are lost after being set once from a static block

Tags: android, static, block

I am working on an Android Project. I have a class with some static fields. I initialise these fields from another class using a static block. But, when the static fields are accessed later in the program, the values set in the fields are lost.

Please refer to the two classes below :

```
public class Constants {
    static {
        String TAG = "Credentials";
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside static block");
        Logger.setCredentials(tempUserId, tempPasswd);
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside static block : Logger.userId : " + 
                Logger.userId + " : Logger.password : " + Logger.password);
        new Logger("Test");
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside static block : After creatinf object : Logger.userId : " + 
            Logger.userId + " : Logger.password : " + Logger.password);

    }
}

public class Logger {
    public static String userId;
    public static String password;

    public static void setCredentials(String userId, String password) {
        Logger.userId = userId;
        Logger.password = password;
        Log.d("Credentials","Inside setCredentials : Logger.userId : " + 
            Logger.userId + " : Logger.password : " + Logger.password);
    }

    public Logger(String tag) {
        super();
        Log.d("Credentials","Inside constructor : Logger.userid : " + 
            Logger.userId + " : Logger.password : " + Logger.password);
        if (Logger.userId == null || Logger.password == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Program output :

Inside static block

Inside setCredentials : Logger.userId : testuser : Logger.password : abc.123

Inside static block : Logger.userId : testuser : Logger.password : abc.123

Inside constructor : Logger.userid : testuser : Logger.password : abc.123

Inside static block : After creatinf object : Logger.userId : testuser : Logger.password : 
abc.123

Inside constructor : Logger.userid : null : Logger.password : null

java.lang.NullPointerException

The code works fine when run as a java application. The field values are lost when run in android. Please suggest what is going wrong?

One more thing, if the exception is handled in the code, then, the static block is called again after exception handling.

Comment: Your control flow is pretty awkward -  it ought to be simplified. iWhere do you get tempuser/ tempPassword?  They outgh to be constants -  why not made logger fields final?

Comment: You cannot be sure in which order your classes are loaded and, thus, in which order their *static* code is executed. So don't rely on one class's static code to initialize another class's fields!

Comment: tempuser/tempPassword are fetched from a DB, only once, when the application is started. The Logger class will be used in developing many more applications. So I initialise its static fields dynamically when the application is started. If i make the fields final and initialise them in the Logger class itself, I will have to modify these fields in every application.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not your problem now, but please consider that Android doesn't give you much control about how long your process lives (and thus, your static variables). Android is free to kill your process (if your application is paused) and re-create it later. You are responsible for saving state, where needed and appropriate.